# Change/Update child value without adding new child (Firebase-swift)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i'm trying to update my child value from my firebase database but the problem is whenever my child value increments by 1, my tableview will automatically create a new child. How can i make it so that it only updates the child value instead? Thank you for your help in advance.

Note: Please see the image for a clearer understanding

```
var ref: DatabaseReference?
var databaseHandle: DatabaseHandle?
var postData = [String]()
var postData2 = [String]()

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        ref = Database.database().reference() //set the firebase reference

        // Retrieve the post and listen for changes
        databaseHandle = ref?.child("Posts").observe(.childChanged, with: { (snapshot) in
            // Code to execute when a child is added under "Posts"
            let post1 = snapshot.key
            let post2 = (snapshot.value as AnyObject).description

            postData.append(post1)
            if let actualPost = post2 {
            postData2.append(actualPost)

            self.tableView.reloadData()

            }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return postData.count
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = postData[indexPath.row]
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = postData2[indexPath.row] + " ★"
        cell.detailTextLabel?.textColor = UIColor.yellow;
        return cell
    }

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you add an element from the list, your datasource count increments in 1, but then your firebase callback for childAdded gets called and now you retrieve the same element you added from the database, causing a duplicate row.

The call that runs when you press the red button isn't present in your example but I'm assuming you do something along those lines. Hope it helps.

Comment: Ok but do u know the codes for it? im quite new to this

Comment: please share the code @IBAction that runs when you tap the red button (and add a new record to the database) with that I can update to a more detailed answer